# Cloning private repository into code-server

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I've set up a private repository on Github and connected code-server to Github. From code-server I can clone public repositories, but not the private one.

Using vscode from windows instead I can work on both private and public repositories. Anyone can help me cloning the private repo? Looking on the issue on github, I tried by inserting the full repository URL, the name of the repo without my username, write the name of the repo and then press enter, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [code-server](https://github.com/coder/code-server) (which allows running VS Code on any machine anywhere and accessing it in the browser), it depends what URL you are using:

- an SSH one ([`coder/code-server` issue 372](https://github.com/coder/code-server/issues/372) shows for instance private key with passphrase are not well supported)
- an HTTPS one (in which case, as [discussed here](https://www.reddit.com/r/codeserver/comments/fub771/saving_git_credentials/), some credential helper would help: `git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout 3600'`)

So experiment between those two URL shemes: if an SSH URL does not work, try (for a private repo) its HTTPS one just to check if that would work.